# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: json, flutter, dart, nsjsonserialization

need your help resolving this error in Flutter...also how to use the instance of this callback on other screens?

> This is my message.json data model

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. "
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. "
    },
]
```

> My message_model.dart

```
class MessagesList {
  final List<Message> messages;

  MessagesList(this.messages);

  factory MessagesList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Message> messages = List<Message>();
    messages = parsedJson.map((e) => Message.fromJson(e)).toList();

    return MessagesList(messages);
  }
}

class Message {
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Message(this.title, this.body);

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Message(
      json['title'].toString(),
      json['body'].toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

> This is my message_services.dart

> _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>') in the loadMessage function (line 3 - fromJson method). Why?

```
Future<String> _loadMessageAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString("./data/message.json");
}

Future loadMessage() async {
  String jsonMessage = await _loadMessageAsset();
  final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(jsonMessage);
  Message message = Message.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  print("Message -- " + message.title);

}
```

Comment: Where did you get this error, on which line? 
You are trying to get list from that map? Map has only String and dynamic type objects, no list type..

Comment: The error is thrown in the 3rd line -"Message.fromJson(jsonResponse)"

Answer (score 0):

messagejson returns JSON array not json object so that is List not Map.

```
 Future loadMessage() async {
   String jsonMessage = await _loadMessageAsset();
  Iterable jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonMessage);
   List<Message > Message = List<Message >.from(jsonResponse ).map((Map model)=> 
   Message .fromJson(model)).toList();
  print("Message -- " + message[0].title);

}
```

Comment: Tried your recommendation but type error prevails!!

Answer (score 0):

The method of rotate the list in the model is wrong. Can you correct it. You will understand if you look carefully.

```
  MessagesList  MessagesList FromJson(String str) => MessagesList 
  .fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String MessagesList ToJson(MessagesList  data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

 class MessagesList  {

  List<Message> flyForData;


   MessagesList ({

     this.messages,

      });
      ////////////this wrong
  factory MessagesList .fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MessagesList (
  
       messages: List<Message>.from(
          json["messages"].map((x) => Message.fromJson(x))),
    
       ); ////////////this wrong

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
 
       "messages": List<dynamic>.from(messages.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  
     };
  }

 class Message {
   final String title;
   final String body;
  Message({
   this.title, this.body
   });

  factory Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Message(
       json['title'].toString(),
     json['body'].toString(),
     );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
       "title": title,
       "body": body,
     };
  }
```